# Solve $x^2 dy/dx = y^2 − 3xy − 5x^2$ for the case of $ y(1)=0$ and describe what the solution looks like when $|x|$ is very large?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found the explicit solution of $x^2 dy/dx = y^2 − 3xy − 5x^2$ for the case of $ y(1)=0$ to equal:

(y/x)^2 - 4(y/x) = 5|x|^-6 + 5  (c=5, where c is the constant) ; using the substitution of y=vx [im not 100% sure if this is correct so i would really appreciate if someone would check for me]

EDIT: Here is my working out:
[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UX7p.jpg)
[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkgMV.jpg)
My problem is what describing how the solution would look like when 'when |x| is very large'

From my knowledge i know that when the constant c>0, y^2 < x^2 but i dont know how that can help.

Thanks!

fyi this is part of my assignment so i'd appreciate if there where no ambiguous answers, im pretty desperate to get this right. Thanks again

Comment: substitute $$y(x)=xv(x)$$ in your equation

Comment: I did that already, did you read what i've written?

Comment: For the asymptotic case $ x \to \infty$ you can divide your original equation by $x^2$ and assume $x \gg y$, which would leave $dy/dx=-5$. Now you can certainly tell how the solution behaves for this case

Comment: yes i have read this and the next steps you Can find in my post

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y'=y^2-3xy-5x^2$$Let $y=xu$ therefore$$xu'+u=u^2-3u-5\\xu'=u^2-4u-5=(u-5)(u+1)\\\dfrac{u'}{(u-5)(u+1)}=\dfrac{1}{x}\\u'[\dfrac{1}{u-5}-\dfrac{1}{u+1}]=\dfrac{6}{x}\to\ln|u-5|-\ln|u+1|=6\ln |x|+C_1\\|\dfrac{u-5}{u+1}|=C_2x^6$$after applying the initial condition ($y(1)=u(1)=0$) we have $C_2=5$ therefore the final answer is $$|\dfrac{y-5x}{y+x}|=5x^6$$for $|x|\to\infty$ , $|\dfrac{y-5x}{y+x}|=|1-\dfrac{6}{u+1}|\to\infty$ which yields to $u\to -1$ or $y\sim -x$

Comment: i uploaded my working, do you mind checking it for me? Where did i go wrong? I would really appreciate your help

Comment: No mind at all! In fact you went wrong from replacing the integrals with the proper functions at the bottom of the page of part 1.

Comment: Also I need to correct my own. I didn't pay attention to initial conditions

Comment: Thanks. I might sound really dumb but i dont understand what you mean, what exactly did i do wrong? I integrated using partial fractions, isnt that what your meant to do? thanks again

Comment: never mind i understand where i went wrong now

Comment: what would i write when x is very close to zero?

Answer (score 0):

then you will have
$$x^2(xv'+v)=-5x^2+x^2v^2-3x^2v$$ and then you will get
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{v(x)^2-4v(x)+5}{x}$$